# How to detect if a UICollectionViewCell is on a specific position? Gif inside

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have made an options menu, similiar to the filter options in snapchat:

[image]

An option snaps to the middle of the screen, you can see it at the rainbow bordered UIView.

Now I want to know which cell is in my rainbow colored view.

How can I detect which option is currently selected?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method you can do:

```
let position = collectionView.contentOffset.x / (cellSize + spacing)
currenIndexPath.item = position
```

And then with that get the selected option